# how to get tags when attribute is chinese in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm not familiar with beautifulsoup's encoding.

when I tackle with some pages,some attribute is chinese, and I want to use this chinese attribute to extract tags.

for example,a html like below:

```
<P class=img_s>
<A href="/pic/93/b67793.jpg" target="_blank" title="查看大图">
<IMG src="/pic/93/s67793.jpg">
</A>
</P>
```

I want to extract the '/pic/93/b67793.jpg'
so what I done is:

```
img_urls = form_soup.findAll('a',title='查看大图')
```

and encounter:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb2 in position 0: ordinalnot in range(128)
```

to tackle with this,I  have done two method,both failed:
one way is :

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```

another way is:

```
response = unicode(response, 'gb2312','ignore').encode('utf-8','ignore')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass in unicode to the findAll method:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8
... 
img_urls = form_soup.findAll('a', title=u'查看大图')
```

Note the [`u` unicode literal marker](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) in front of the title value. You do need to [specify an encoding on your source file](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) for this to work (the `coding` comment at the top of the file), or switch to unicode escape codes instead:

```
img_urls = form_soup.findAll('a', title=u'\u67e5\u770b\u5927\u56fe')
```

Internally, BeautifulSoup uses unicode, but you are passing it a byte-string with non-ascii characters in them. BeautifulSoup tries to decode that to unicode for you and fails as it doesn't know what encoding you used. By providing it with ready-made unicode instead you side-step the issue.

Working example:

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> example = u'<P class=img_s>\n<A href="/pic/93/b67793.jpg" target="_blank" title="<A href="/pic/93/b67793.jpg" target="_blank" title="\u67e5\u770b\u5927\u56fe"><IMG src="/pic/93/s67793.jpg"></A></P>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(example)
>>> soup.findAll('a', title=u'\u67e5\u770b\u5927\u56fe')
[<a href="/pic/93/b67793.jpg" target="_blank" title="查看大图"><img src="/pic/93/s67793.jpg" /></a>]
```

Comment: how to find each chinese's correspond unicode.such 查看大图  = \u67e5\u770b\u5927\u56fe ,where to find it？thx pieters

Comment: you give me an idea,if i could replace all non-ascii characters to unicode,so that beautifulsoup can work with non-english pages.

Comment: @young001: I just typed `u'` on a python prompt, copied and pasted your ideograms, then added another closing `'` and hit enter. Python then showed me the unicode escapes.

Answer (score 1):

Beautiful Soup 4.1.0 [will automatically convert attribute values from UTF-8](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-string), which solves this problem: